# Intermittent: "Unable to instantiate Action"

Tags: java, struts2, websphere

I have a struts2 application running on WebSphere 7. I've recently added a feature to this (pre-existing application) and have run into an unusual problem.  When I fire off the new action About 1 time in 3 I get the error listed below.  If I get it once, I get it every time after that.  However if I go out to the front page of the application and come back in (i.e., resetting much of the application state, but not touching the server), it usually works (we get a new 1 in 3 "roll" basically).  This also happens with sub actions to this feature.

stack trace:

```
[9/9/13 12:51:32:289 EDT] 00000028 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Unable to instantiate Action, com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction,  defined for 'GeneralNotesUpdateNote' in namespace '/'null]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: Unable to instantiate Action, com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction,  defined for &#39;GeneralNotesUpdateNote&#39; in namespace &#39;/&#39;null
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:637)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1187)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:839)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:533)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1043)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:963)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

I've loaded the struts source and the original error seems to be a NPE (re)reading the configuration.  Why this works sometimes and not others is curious.

pruned struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="com.sssa.ebb.core.utils.EbbResourceBundle" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/loadImage|/SaveReviewCaseServlet|/getFile|/displayPDF"></constant>

    <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
    <include file="decisions.xml"/>

<package name="default" extends="json-default" >
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="userProfile" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.interceptors.UserProfileInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="timeActions" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.interceptors.EbbActionTimerInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="valueStackManipulator" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.interceptors.ValueStackInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="actionHistoryRecorder" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.interceptors.ActionHistoryInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.interceptors.CachingHeadersInterceptor"/>

        <interceptor-stack name="ebb_default_stack">
            <interceptor-ref name="timeActions"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="userProfile"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="valueStackManipulator"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionHistoryRecorder"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="ebb_default_stack"/>

    <global-results>
        <result name="shutdown" >/jsps/common/shutdown.jsp</result>
        <result name="ebbSearch" >/jsps/caseselection/ebbSearch.jsp</result>
        <result name="ebbForward" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">${forwardAction}</param>
        </result>
        <result name="systemerror" >/jsps/common/systemerror.jsp</result>
        <result name="applicationerror" >/jsps/common/applicationerror.jsp</result>
        <result name="systemfailure" >/jsps/common/systemfailure.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="com.sssa.ebb.ejb.exceptions.EbbEJBException" result="systemerror" />
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="systemfailure" />
    </global-exception-mappings>


    <action name="exitAction" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.ExitAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">exitApplication</result>
    </action>

    <action name="enterEbbSearch" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.EbbSearchAction">
        <result>/jsps/caseselection/ebbSearch.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="openGeneralNotes" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction">
        <result name="success">/jsps/common/generalnotes.jsp</result>
        <result name="viewpage">/jsps/common/generalnotes.jsp</result>

    </action>

    <action name="GeneralNotesAddNote" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction" method="addNote">
        <result type="json">
             <param name="root">jsonResponse</param>
        </result>
    </action>   

    <action name="GeneralNotesUpdateNote" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction" method="updateNote">
        <result type="json">
             <param name="root">jsonResponse</param>
        </result>
    </action>   

    <action name="GeneralNotesDeleteNote" class="com.sssa.ebb.web.actions.common.GeneralNotesAction" method="deleteNote">
    </action>   

</package>
```

Not sure what all else to add, TIA.

Comment: Are you using Spring or another dependency injection framework? Are you using a custom ObjectFactory for Struts2?

Comment: No Spring.  We are using OpenJPA for persistence.  And no custom ObjectFactory either.

Comment: The default `ObjectFactory` just uses reflection. I'm guessing that the stack trace being reported isn't actually the problem and some other unreported exception is occurring that is leading to that. I'd set breakpoints and step through.